# loading large data in kendoui combobox using transport

Tags: kendo-ui

I m loading 5000 data  in kendoui comobobox using transport property also setting ajax time 10secs .the loading exceeds the ajax timings sometimes it could not load the data in combobox.
can anyone help me

Comment: Why are you loading 5000 records in the kendo UI use Custom Paging as you have Large Data.

Comment: You either need a faster server call/response for the 5000 records, or you need to deliver those items down with the page.  Otherwise, you are stuck setting the timeout on the $.ajax call and waiting.

Comment: what is the solution using javascript or jqery